# Using vlookup to find matching strings and report a value from an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

Per [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsMNX.png)
 (worksheet uploaded here: https://files.fm/u/87ydgawy), I have four columns. Two correspond to an old code and corresponding description (left), while the other two refer to the new code and description (right).

I am aiming to look up the description for a new code in the list of descriptions for the old codes and then, if there's a match, report the old code.

The VLOOKUP in its current form does not work, reporting a #N/A error. I thought it might be due to the fact I'm using strings, but the data format of the columns is set to text, and a simple =A=B comes back as true.

Any idea how to get the VLOOKUP to work as intended?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup searches in first column:

Try:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$2413,MATCH(F1,$B$1:$B$2413,0))
```

Comment: Bingo. Amendment of an apparent typo required, but otherwise seems to do the job: =INDEX($A$1:$A$2413,MATCH(F1,$B$1:$B$2413,0)).

Thank you!